# PersonalVec.hpp:12: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘;’ token error

Tags: c++

I got this error and I can't figure out why.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

#ifndef PERSONALVEC_HPP_
#define PERSONALVEC_HPP_

template <class T,class PrnT>

class PersonalVec
{
public:
    PersonalVec() {}

    ~PersonalVec()
    {
        //TODO: delete vector.
    }

    void push_back(T& obj)
    {
        int index = rand()%_vec.size();
    }

private:
    vector<T*> _vec;
};

#endif /* PERSONALVEC_HPP_ */
```

Comment: Did you include the headers needed for `vector` and `rand`, and why aren't you writing the correct namespace?

Comment: line 12 is an empty line (one upper than template<...>

Comment: I included cstdio and vector.

Comment: so the error is probably on the line above `template<....>`  What's that line?

Comment: maybe I have studied it wrong but that how you define a template, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `rand` and `vector` are in the std namespace. 
Use

```
private:
std::vector<T*> _vec;
```

and

```
std::rand()
```

Comment: but I didn't need to ass std:: to rand

Comment: @benjamin, rand seems to be both in the std:: and the global :: namespace.

Comment: Don't rely on that. with `<cstdlib>`, it's `std::rand`. Anything else is a luxury or coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
int index = rand()%_vec.size();
```

You call the function `rand()` but do not include the header which declares it. Specifically, you need to add the following line to the top of your program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is likely that you are using a `vector` without being in the `std` namespace.  change `vector<T*> _vec` to `std::vector<T*> _vec`.

The following code (Ideone linky: http://www.ideone.com/HgL1e) seems to work fine.

```
#include <vector> 
#include <cstdlib> 

template <class T,class PrnT> 
class PersonalVec 
{ 
public: 
    PersonalVec() {} 

    ~PersonalVec() 
    { 
        //TODO: delete vector. 
    } 

    void push_back(T& obj) 
    { 
        int index = rand()%_vec.size(); 
    } 

private: 
    std::vector<T*> _vec; 
}; 

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    PersonalVec<int, int> testVec;
    testVec.push_back(i);
    return 0;
}
```